# Can my dapp charge tokens without asking for user permission?

Tags: contract-invocation, tokens, dapps

For instance, say clicking on a button will perform some type of action and it charges the user 1 token, but doesn't show any pop-up dialogs.

I don't want a Metamask window opening up to submit a transaction everytime a tx might occur, since it could ruin the user experience. The user would agree to the terms and conditions allowing the dapp to consume tokens without their explicit permission of course.

I just want to know, is this possible with smart contracts and how?

Comment: I think one could write such a contract. You'd have a method on the contract restricted to being called by you or one of your agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) has a function called `approve(address _spender, uint _value)` which allows a user to give permission to your address or contract (`_spender`) to debit your token up to the specified amount (`_value`). Once approved, you can transfer funds on their behalf using `transferFrom()`.

So have your user approve a single transaction in Metamask giving your address or contract permission to debit their funds, then you can perform any future operations on their behalf without them needing to approve another transaction through Metamask.

Note that you will still need to somehow get a transaction to the network to debit these funds; The obvious way to do it would be to run a server-side process listening for user actions, somehow validating that they really came from the user in question and sending transactions for them behind the scenes.

PS. If the user is going to be clearing you to debit funds used in many small transactions in any case, you may also want to look at different approaches, in particular state channels, which don't require either them or you to keep sending transactions to the blockchain. For example, see [this proposal for fast, verifiable off-chain gambling](http://www.blunderingcode.com/gamble-channels-fast-verifiable-off-chain-gambling/).

Comment: I've done as you said, but `transferFrom()` doesn't debit the amount from the user's balance even though it returns `true`.

Comment: Link to your code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rosendin/1a2f1e275d27caad8b45b3a6203328a3

Comment: Sorry, I meant the test code that isn't doing what you expect. Your contract looks fine, no reason `transferFrom` wouldn't work if you're calling it right.

Comment: This is the general idea: https://gist.github.com/rosendin/07e8e8c99b154e01290728c12f48b871

End-user clicks an approve button, and some external event triggers `transferFrom()` intermittently but the balance stays the same.

Comment: transferFrom needs to be called by the account you approved, not the account that did the approving.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Now I'm getting `Error: could not unlock signer account`.

Comment: Nvm, have it working now. I had to change the transfer amount to an integer for some reason (even though the contract specifies 10 decimals) and I sent from my personal 0th account to my personal 1st account. Not sure why I'm getting the above error, but at least `transferFrom()` works. Thanks.